# Tearing only in Google Chrome

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, google-chrome, xfce, tearing

I am using Xubuntu 15.04 and GeForce GT 630.

Also I am using this hack https://github.com/chjj/compton/wiki/vsync-guide (last point) and nvidia drivers 355.11 to prevent tearing in Xfce.

Everything is ok with all application but I still see tearing in Google Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.101): in Youtube video, web applications like Google Maps and so on, but no in Firefox.

Is it possible somehow to fix this issue?

Comment: I have this same problem with Chrome and in a completely different situation (KDE, AMD graphics, 14.04), which leads me to believe it's a bug in Chrome itself. You can try using Chromium instead, which is pretty much the same thing, just open-source. It may work.

Comment: Looks the same.

Comment: I have two laptops with old Nvidia and Xubuntu 16.04 with no composition. Both use the same driver 340.102. In the other tearing happens in Chrome: Quadro FX 570M. In the other it does not happen: Geforce 9400M. I can not find any difference in settings. The setting ForceFullCompositionPipeline is not available for these.

Comment: Now tearing is gone in Quadro FX 570M. I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created custom xorg.conf for Nvidia card for avoiding tearing (see below). As you can see main line there is:

```
 Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

In case of failure try to generate own xorg.conf. Each update of Nvidia's drivers can replace your xorg.conf, thats why just replace it again.

This hack also fixed tearing in web-videos.

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 364.19  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-11)  Tue Apr 19 15:22:17 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Chrome settings > Show advanced settings... and disable "Use hardware acceleration when available".

It worked for me.